# count how many are in L_df but not in A_df in spark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, pyspark

I can count how many are in L_df but not in A_df (in their 'id' column) in numpy:

```
missing_data = np.isin(L_df['id'], A_df['id'], invert=True).sum()
```

What is the equivalent code in PySpark to count number of missing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `anti` join. Quoting the documentation from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join)

> **Anti Join**:
> An anti join returns values from the left relation that has no match with the right. It is also referred to as a left anti join.

Assuming you load the dataframes `L_df` and `A_df` as spark dataframes, you can use [DataFrame.join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) with `anti` join as follows:

```
L_df.join(A_df, on='id', how='anti').count()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I checked 'Join', but I used it in a wrong way. Thanks a lot for the correct form.

Comment: could you please inform me about the following one:  `missing_data = np.isin(L_df['id_1'], A_df['id_2'], invert=True).sum()`  where 'id_1' is different from 'id_2'

Comment: @Fatemeh Hi, could you create a new question with an example input data and expected output to refer to it here so I can help you better? Thanks

Comment: FYI, if the column names are different but they have the same format, you can still rename the column before doing the join I suggested above. This can help you rename : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed.html